# python: non-regex equiv of re.findall

Tags: python, regex, match, findall

I was wondering if any of the following exist in python:

- A: non-regex equivalent of "re.findall()".
- B: a way of neutralizing regex special characters in a variable before passing to findall().

I am passing a variable to re.findall which runs into problems when the variable has a period or a slash or a carat etc because I would like these characters to be interpreted literally. I realize it is not necessary to use regex to do this job, but I like the behavior of re.findall() because it returns a list of every match it finds.  This allows me to easily count how many times the substring exists by using len().

Here's an example of my code:

```
>>substring_matches = re.findall(randomVariableOfCharacters, document_to_be_searched)
>>
>>#^^ will return something like ['you', 'you', 'you']
>>#but could also return something like ['end.', 'end.', 'ends']
>>#if my variable is 'end.' because "." is a wildcard.
>>#I would rather it return ['end.', 'end.']
>>
>>occurrences_of_substring = len(substring_matches)
```

I'm hoping to not have to use string.find(), if possible.  Any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: (B:) [re.escape](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) for regexes, but there is probably a better method (A).

Comment: Start over with your description, please. Without mentioning regexes, what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [str.count()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) if you only want the number of occurances, but its not equivalent to [re.findall()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) it only gets the count.

```
document_to_be_searched = "blabla bla bla."
numOfOcur = document_to_be_searched.count("bl")
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  This approach is much more elegant.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay I hope it helped, mate.

Answer (score 3):

Sure: looking at your code, I think that you're looking for is `string.count`.

```
>>> 'abcdabc'.count('abc')
2
```

Note that however, this is *not* an equivalent to `re.findall`; although it looks more appropriate in your case.

Comment: Whoa, waaay better than my approach.  Thank you!